# Limit with integral and $x^3$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin\sqrt{t}\, dt}{x^3}.$$

Comment: L'Hôpital will work.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with? In its current state, your question is something that you can just plug into WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 2):

Use L'Hôpital combined with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's Rule gives too simple a solution, so we give a more complicated one.

Because $\lim_{w\to 0} \frac{\sin w}{w}=1$, it follows that for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, and  for $t$ close enough to $0$ the inequality
$$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\sqrt{t}\lt \sin \sqrt{t}\lt \sqrt{t}$$
holds. Thus if $x\gt 0$ is small enough, we have
$$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\int_0^{x^2} t^{1/2}\,dt \lt \int_0^{x^2} \sin(\sqrt{t})\,dt\lt \int_0^{x^2} t^{1/2}\,dt.$$
Thus if $x$ is positive and small enough, then 
$$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\lt \frac{\int_0^{x^2} \sin(\sqrt{t})\,dt}{x^3}\lt \frac{2}{3}.$$
The result now follows by Squeezing.

Answer (score 1):

By l'hopital rule  we have $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin\sqrt{t} dt}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sin x}{3x^2}=\frac{2}{3}$$